# Como fazer essa consulta com JPA?

Tags: java, sql, jpa, criteria

Gostaria de duas soluções para essa pergunta, uma usando uma typedquery normal e outra usando o criteria devido a sua grande versatilidade para o código.

Eis a minha query:

```
      TypedQuery<Pessoa> query = em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM Pessoa a where  
      a.dataNascimento <> '12/9/2000'", Pessoa.class);
```

como fazer para retornar essa query?

Aqui esta o erro:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.time.LocalDate
```

Comment: Você mesmo já deu a solução com `TypedQuery` em sua pergunta. Isso significa que você só quer a solução com `Criteria`? Ou por algum motivo você também quer algo mais com `TypedQuery` que não seja isso que você já deu na pergunta?

Comment: @VictorStafusa O problema é que quando rodo essa query ela dá um erro !!

Comment: Qual erro? Coloque o erro na pergunta.

Answer (score 2):

Tente modificar seu where "a.dataNascimento <> '12/9/2000'"

como o igual "="

ficaria assim: "a.dataNascimento = '12/9/2000' "

//////////////////////////

Bom, acho que o problema gira em torno do retorno do método que contém sua query, certo?
Bom, acho que o este método deve resolver, usando o setParamenter...kkk

```
public Pessoa buscaDataNasc(String dataNascimento){
        Pessoa pessoa = this.manager.createQuery("select p from Pessoa p where p.dataNascimento = :pDataNascimento")
                .setParameter("pDataNascimento", dataNascimento).getResultList();

        return pessoa;
    }
```

ps: não tenho muita afinidade com a API de criteria.

Comment: Tentei fazer dá o mesmo erro! Acho que temos que usar o .setParameter

Comment: já tentou "a.dataNascimento = '12-09-2000' "?

Comment: Sim ! Lembrando que eu quero <> e não =

Comment: vc tem razão, temos que usar o .setParameter.
Bom, simulei um contexto semelhante a esse problema e funcionou.

Comment: Tá dando erro porque data é String e não Date. No setParameter passa um Date e não uma String. Para converter a String para Date dá uma olhada aqui: https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-string-to-date-java/

Comment: Pois é, levando em consideração que questão não deixou claro o tipo do dado "dataNascimento" e a assinatura que ele trata a variável na query (12/9/2000), supus que tratava-se de uma String. Por isso o método recebe o parâmetro String  dataNascimento.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que parece o erro é no formato da data...

Eu tive um erro parecido, o problema esta na busca pelo formato '12/9/2000' que é formato Brasileiro, e o BD geralmente trabalha com o internacional que é '2000-09-12'

Tente fazer a busca dessa maneira...
 "a.dataNascimento = '2000-09-12' "

Comment: A questão não é formato, mas "java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.time.LocalDate"